# Programmatically navigate with react router v4 and passing jsx to target component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx, react-router-v4

I have a component which displays info supplied in props.

Is there a way to programmatically navigate to this component and pass to him **jsx** code?

With simple string (not jsx) I would do something like the following:

```
this.props.history.push("/mycomponent", { message: "Just a text" });
```

and in target component:

```
const {message} = this.props.location.state;
```

However, if I include in `message` any jsx node, ie. `Smiley <i className="far fa-smile"/>` it displays as plain text.

Is there any way to achieve this other than using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`? If not is it safe to use it in this context?

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    returnMessage = () => {
        // this.props.location.state.message = 'Smiley <i className="far fa-smile"/>'
        return {__html: this.props.location.state.message};
    }
    render() {
      return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={returnMessage()} />;
    }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: can you not just render like this since it's just a string? `return <div>{this.props.location.state.message}</div>` [edit] oh I see you want to also include html

Comment: I like the answer I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46832912/is-dangerouslysetinnerhtml-the-only-way-to-render-html-from-an-api-in-react

Comment: While there are other ways to parse that string into html (or jsx) they really run into the same vulnerabilities where a user might inject a script tag or something malicious. So if you just sanitize your data and make your back end safe you should be g2g.

Comment: @MichaelSorensen Indeed. I guess the initial title has misled you. Sorry.